# Error Occurred in Deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, access-denied

We have more than 3 developers working on a single solution file. Because of this, we cannot add them all in the site collection administrator menu.

When I deploy with administrator credentials in Visual Studio, I am able to successfully deploy to the particular SharePoint Application. When I login with any of these users, I am not able to. It gives me the below error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': 
<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied
```

We have given administrative rights for these users' login to the Active Directory.

What can we do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check all causes at [Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/07/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-recycle-iis-application-pool-the-local-sharepoint-server-is-not-available-check-that-the-server-is-running-and-connected-to-the-sharepoint-farm/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried all the possible solutions with Active Directory, IIS Authentication and finally was able to fix the issue just by doing the below. Hope this will help you in similar kind of issue.

1. Do a IIS reset
2. Check if IIS is resetting.
3. If it is not, then disable UAC from control panel and IIS reset will work.
4. Go to Central Administration site
5. Navigate to the Manage Web Applications page
6. Click on the web application that hosts the site you are trying to deploy to
7. Click the User Policy ribbon item.
8. Add your windows account to the list of users with the Full Control permission.

It worked for me!

Comment: Second step worked for me. What is strange is that I had been deploying to the same server for weeks without any issues. Suddenly it stopped working, and started again to work after setting User Policy for the user.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you're a site collection admin

Comment: Well for me it does provide an answer. I had the issue and this corrected it for me.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me:

- Open the Sharepoint SQL Server database in Management Studio. The default name of it is `SHAREPOINTWEB`.
- Under the Security folder, right click Logins and add the user who needs to deploy solutions. Grant them `db_owner` schema.

Comment: I had the specific error of "the local sharepoint server is not available". This solution helped resolve that error.

Answer (score 5):

OFFTOPIC:

> Even though the problem is solved for the original poster, I came here because I had the same issue, and these solutions (and more found in the internet) didn't help me. This being said...

On-topic:

I'll add the solution that worked for me (in order to avoid duplicates), because it may help someone else:

***Deploy the solution to fully created site collection***

In Visual Studio 2010-2012:

1. Right click the Solution you want to deploy (in the Solution explorer)
2. Go to Properties
3. Go to the "Site URL" attribute. If the Site's URL you want to deploy it is incomplete (i.e: the port you are working on is missing), change it.

[image: Example]

This happened to me, since it was targeting `http://webservice/`  instead of `http://webservice:123/`

[Source](http://spsdev.blogspot.com/2013/03/access-denied-while-deploying-solution.html)

Comment: I was having the same problem, and this is the only one that fixed it. Dumb me had the wrong port.

Comment: I even had the incorrect site, instead of machineName/sites/mySite I only had machineName there

Answer (score 2):

adding user as a `db_owner` of the content database solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I closed and opened visual studio and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Run the Visual Studio as administrator and problem will be solved if any with Visual Studio permission.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when I opened my SharePoint project in Visual Studio and then started my local SharePoint and SQL services (don't leave them running all the time to conserve resources).

The error went away once I closed and restarted Visual Studio once I verified SharePoint was running correctly in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar situation a year ago and fixed it but then I forgot how i did that. Last night once again it came up. I was trying to deploy a sharepoint solution and this error came up.

if you can then try to **restart the server**. Sometimes it takes care of most of the problems.

if not then make sure to add your machine's administrator account to sharepoint administration as full control. Why? because when you are deploying via Visual Studio you have to **run Visual Studio as Administrator.** So you need to **ensure that sharepoint is also allowing this login** to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the issue now and then, but it once worked by changing the namespace and then I proceeded, but actually the issue was with the application pool account being locked due to password expiry and while resetting the IIS the app pool got disabled.

**So the issue was the App pool account getting locked.**

Regards
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer because even as of SharePoint 2016 (Singer-Server Farm - aka Development Farm) and deploying with Visual Studio 2017, I was still getting this problem.  Trying each of these answers was not giving me success.

In my case, re-running the [SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt634361(v=office.16).aspx) with your default settings, always solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

One more potential fix for this, as the steps in this thread didn't work for me:

I had to assign myself as the site collection administrator

1. Central Administration
2. Application management
3. Change site collection administrators
4. Primary Site Collection Administrator => **Your account**

Answer (score -1):

On the IIS console, checked settings under Authentication.
Enable windows and anonymous authentication.

Comment: No Luck Garish... In the sharepoint application, we have used forms authentication aswell.